# Swift how should I store chat nickNames?

Tags: php, mysql

So I made a swift chat app that first requests a php file to load older messages from the mysql adatbase, and then I set up the real time chat with socket.io

Whenever a user sends a message it requests a php file which checks if the text is valid, then I do the encryption and store the new message in encrypted version in the database and I send the original message with socket.io to the correct user

---

What would be a good way to store user datas that are changing? (Nickname, profile picture)

**The current swift array that holds the messages inself** looks like this:

```
....| chatRooms
........| chatRoomId
........| messages(array)
............| userId
............| message
```

It would not be a good idea to store the nicknames with the messages I know, because the messages are getting cached and if the user quits & reloads the app, the cached nickname will show for older messages and the new one for the new messages.

- Maybe I should make a userData array in the chatRooms? Or outside it? And save all the current talking-to user ids inside it then every minute request a PHP file to load nicknames?

What do you suggest guys?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using an userId it would be obvious you need a new entity **Users** with the ID, nickname, profile picture etc...

If your objective is to limit queryes and load new profiles only when needed then you could broadcast a message from the server indicating which userId has changed data, since you are using websockets. This is to avoid reloading all the data every time (the problem is of course the profile pictures)